# Could not go to to page for Open Ticket

Tags: ibm-cloud

After "Go to bluemix support" I am forward to "Welcome to the Client Success Portal". When I choice Service "IBM Bluemix" and on left panel I fulfill my Bluemix username and password, I re-directed back to "Welcome to the Client Success Portal"

Answer (score 0):

You should select the service "IBM Bluemix" and then click on the "Go to sign in" button under that drop down. You do not sign in using the left hand panel.